# Java String attribute

Tags: java

I came across this statement and i have never seen it before:

```
String caseTag = tag.toLowerCase(), attrib;
```

I see that there is an Attribute class but i don't understand what the above statement does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just declaring two string variables and initializing the first one to `tag.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `attrib` variable defined, it just defines it and sets it to `null`

If you have - it does not compile (duplicate variable).

Comment: It does compile, and declares two string variables.

Answer (score 0):

As @takteek says, it is declaring two string variables and initializing one of them.

The reason you've not come across this before is that most Java style guides recommend against using this form of declaration ...